# How to draw an arc in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uiview

I have some percentage values that takes from the web service. According to the percentage value I want to draw some arcs in a `UIView`in the following way.

[image]

White circle is an `UIView` and I tried in this way to achieve this.

```
func colorProgress()
{
    let circleColorPath=UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint.init(x: RDcircleEnum.circleCenterX.getValues(), y: RDcircleEnum.circleCenterY.getValues()), radius: self.innerCircleRadius, startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi*self.progressAmount), clockwise: true)



    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = circleColorPath.cgPath

    //change the fill color
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    //you can change the stroke color
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    //you can change the line width
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 3.0
    self.progressColor.setFill()
    circleColorPath.fill()
}
```

But this doesn't gives what I want. I want to draw arcs in different lengths according to the percentage value. Please help me.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/darrarski/DRCircularProgress-iOS

Answer (score 1):

Here is the perfect logic here for what you want to achieve:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97615/draw-an-arc-based-on-a-given-percentage

**Custom UIView Class**

```
import UIKit

class DemoView: UIView {

var startPoint: CGFloat = 0
var color: UIColor = UIColor.yellow
var trackColor: UIColor = UIColor.gray
var trackWidth: CGFloat = 1
var fillPercentage: CGFloat = 100

override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

} // init

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

} // init

private func getGraphStartAndEndPointsInRadians() -> (graphStartingPoint: CGFloat, graphEndingPoint: CGFloat) {

    // make sure our starting point is at least 0 and less than 100
    if ( 0 > self.startPoint ) {
        self.startPoint = 0
    } else if ( 100 < self.startPoint ) {
        self.startPoint = 100
    } // if

    // make sure our fill percentage is at least 0 and less than 100
    if ( 0 > self.fillPercentage ) {
        self.fillPercentage = 0
    } else if ( 100 < self.fillPercentage ) {
        self.fillPercentage = 100
    } // if

    // we take 25% off the starting point, so that a zero starting point
    // begins at the top of the circle instead of the right side...
    self.startPoint = self.startPoint - 25

    // we calculate a true fill percentage as we need to account
    // for the potential difference in starting points
    let trueFillPercentage = self.fillPercentage + self.startPoint

    let π: CGFloat = .pi

    // now we can calculate our start and end points in radians
    let startPoint: CGFloat = ((2 * π) / 100) * (CGFloat(self.startPoint))
    let endPoint: CGFloat = ((2 * π) / 100) * (CGFloat(trueFillPercentage))

    return(startPoint, endPoint)

} // func

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    // first we want to find the centerpoint and the radius of our rect

    let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
    let radius: CGFloat = rect.width / 2

    // make sure our track width is at least 1
    if ( 1 > self.trackWidth) {
        self.trackWidth = 1
    } // if

    // and our track width cannot be greater than the radius of our circle
    if ( radius < self.trackWidth ) {
        self.trackWidth = radius
    } // if

    // we need our graph starting and ending points
    let (graphStartingPoint, graphEndingPoint) = self.getGraphStartAndEndPointsInRadians()

    // now we need to first draw the track...
    let trackPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius - (trackWidth / 2), startAngle: graphStartingPoint, endAngle: 2.0 * .pi, clockwise: true)
    trackPath.lineWidth = trackWidth
    self.trackColor.setStroke()
    trackPath.stroke()

    // now we can draw the progress arc
    let percentagePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius - (trackWidth / 2), startAngle: graphStartingPoint, endAngle: graphEndingPoint, clockwise: true)
    percentagePath.lineWidth = trackWidth
    percentagePath.lineCapStyle = .round
    self.color.setStroke()
    percentagePath.stroke()

    return

} // func } // class
```

**Implementation in viewController:**

```
 let demoView : DemoView = DemoView()
 demoView.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
 demoView.trackWidth = 5
 demoView.startPoint = 0
 demoView.fillPercentage = 25
 self.view.addSubview(demoView)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer, you need to change the strokeEnd property to show the percentage.

```
shapeLayer.strokeEnd = percentage/100;
```

Answer (score 0):

For that you should push some logic.

You should consider `100 % equals to 360° (degree)` as angle.

Now for example if you have `50 % progress` then your `end angle` should be of `180°`

Comment: I tried this way. And let say I have 90% then the end angle is 324. I got start angle as 0 and the end angle 324 but I get a complete circle

Answer (score 0):

@Hima's answers works but raises `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0` exceptions, which may become problematic in the future.

As an alternative, I draw the arc with:

```
func drawSector(rect: CGRect, radius: CGFloat, start: CGFloat, span: CGFloat, lineThickness: CGFloat, color: UIColor) {
    let angleStartRadians = CGFloat(2 * .pi * (start - 0.25))  // offset by 25% to have the 0 at the top
    let angleEndRadians = CGFloat(2 * .pi * (start + span - 0.25)) // offset by 25% to have the 0 at the top
    let center: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
    let percentagePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: radius - (lineThickness / 2), startAngle: angleStartRadians, endAngle: angleEndRadians, clockwise: true)
    let shape = CAShapeLayer()
    myView.layer.addSublayer(shape)
    shape.strokeColor = color.cgColor
    shape.fillColor = .none
    shape.lineWidth = lineThickness
    shape.lineCap = .butt
    shape.path = percentagePath.cgPath
}
```